# No Camunda BPMN Model API Documentation regarding creating Arrows, Circle, Rectangle Shapes

Tags: camunda, bpmn.io

I read documentation about Camunda BPMN Model API [here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/model-api/bpmn-model-api/). 
But there is no documentation for drawing start event, end event, task shapes and arrows programatically using that library.

Answer (score 3):

You can create all the BPMN shapes by your own. The Model API has currently no feature to auto generate DI element. For example see this [test](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpmn-model/blob/dbaccc59c5e6a4f97dc5e2480c903cfa3d0c359b/src/test/java/org/camunda/bpm/model/bpmn/BpmnDiTest.java#L170) how to create DI elements with the Model API.

Comment: I edited my question, I knew there were methods to draw the shapes programatically using the api and I had hard time understanding it.